# fetch_all does not return anything

Tags: php, mysql

Still a PHP Novice. I got PHP Version 5.6.2 using it with MAMP.
I am trying to get all table entries. Code is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM atable";
$result = $db_connection->query($query);
if(!$result){
    $msg = $db_connection->error;
    die("The query failed! <br/>" . $msg);
} 
else {
    echo "Successfull query.";
}
```

Everything ok until here.
The fetch_assoc() works too:

```
$output = $result->fetch_assoc();
print_r($output);
```

But fetch_all() doesn't work:

```
$output = $result->fetch_all();
print_r($output);
```

I tried getting an error message but received none.

I read that older Versions of PHP do not allow fetch_all and so I tried with a while loop, which again worked just fine. What am I doing wrong? :(

Thx for your help!

Comment: Let us see more code regarding this!

Comment: Note: if you do not have `mysqlnd` in your environment, you may not have this method.

Comment: can you show what is the error ?

Comment: @Ghost Thank you. I just checked, and indeed I do not have `mysqlnd` but `libmysqlclient`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing `execute();`

Answer (score 0):

you should use fetch_assoc() with a loop instead of fetch_all()

Answer (score 0):

Try `pg_fetch_all()`

```
$output = $result->pg_fetch_all();
print_r($output);
```

**pg_fetch_all() returns an array that contains all rows (records) in the result resource.**